# On the density of vector fields with only nondegenerate zeroes

Tags: differential-topology

Suppose we have a manifold $X$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the vector field $v_u(p) : X \rightarrow TX$ by taking the point $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to its natural (orthogonal) projection onto $TX_p$. How can we show that the set of $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that every zero of $v_u$ is nondegenerate is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make any sense.  For example, is $M$ supposed to be $X$?  If the vector field is only defined on $X$, how can we end up with a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Fixed. $M$ was supposed to be an $X$.

Comment: Oh, and ignore my second question; I misunderstood.  Sorry! :-)

Comment: It looks like the Morse lemma could be useful.